# wp_enqueue_script Doesn't Work?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

It's pretty standard, I enqueue script and style for admin page.

```
function admin_custom(){
    wp_enqueue_script('js', plugins_url('adm.js', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('css', plugins_url('adm.css', __FILE__));
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_custom');
```

The result:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='css-css'  href='http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/manager/adm.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/manager/adm.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
```

But it doesn't work. Style is working, but the script is not loaded. I put the css and js in the same folder. It doesn't make sense for me. Any help will be appreciated, I spent last day for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: when you say the script is not loaded, is it returning a 404?

Comment: @Milo: I used inspect element in Chrome, when I clicked css link, my code was there, but when I clicked js link, it was blank.

Comment: That code should work, and does work when I test it. Make sure the path is correct and check the permissions on the file.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem too, turns out the function  `wp_enqueue_scripts()`, removes any blank spaces from your template directory folders. So say your folder name is `this theme`, the function will make it `thistheme`, which will then cause an incorrect directory link. Try changing the folder names around if this is the case, otherwise it worked for me so good luck!

Comment: An additional note: this is because (unencoded) spaces are invalid characters in URLs. Even if `wp_enqueue_scripts` didn't strip the spaces there is a good chance the URL wouldn't work.